# Form background transparency but still have click events

Tags: c#, winforms, mono

I have been trying to work out if this is possible.

Essentially what I want is to have a form with a border as normal but with a transparent background.  In this area I want a live display of what's behind (a video feed is highly likely) into which I can capture the click events to display further information onto my overly form.

Currently I have tried to use Form.TransparencyKey and BackColor but I then lose the click events in the transparent sections of the from.  I have also attempted to use a 99% transparent png as the BackgroundImage, but this just gives a dark gray background.

I have noted if I draw to the gap (ie a simple line) I can capture the click events over these, just not the transparent sections.  Is there way I could draw a semi transparent rectangle in the on paint first maybe?

I would like this to be mono compatible if at all possible.

Comment: Any part of a window that's transparent to the eye is transparent to mouse events as well.  This is by design and cannot be changed.  If the windows belong to the same thread then use IMessageFilter.  If not then you'll need a low-level mouse hook, set by SetWindowsHookEx().  Beware that transparency overlays on video tends to work poorly, they use the same video hardware feature.  Heavy flicker is not uncommon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this has turned out to be impossible I ended up floating a 2nd dynamically generated form over the top with Opacity set to 0.01.  I then used the Resize and LocationChanged events on the main form to resize and move the overlay form as required.  I then just needed to handle the overlay forms click event to do as I needed.

```
public MainFrom()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        f = new Form();
        f.Size = panel1.Size;
        f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        f.BackColor = Color.Black;
        f.Opacity = 0.01;
        f.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        f.Show(this);

        f.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.UserClicked);
    }
```

This code then resizes the overlay form to account for the main forms border:

```
private void SetLocation()
        {
            // These next 2 lines calculate the width of the border 
            // and the title bar and then use these to off set the floating
            // forms location correctly.
            int xOffset = (this.Width - this.ClientSize.Width) / 2;
            int yOffset= this.Height - this.ClientSize.Height - xOffset;
            int x = this.Location.X + panel1.Location.X + xOffset;
            int y = this.Location.Y + panel1.Location.Y + yOffset;
            f.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
```

According to the MoMa tool this is 100% mono compatible and the code compiles in MonoDevelop as expected.  However if I run this I am seeing a null reference exception I do not see in MS .NET on load, this might be fixable but I am yet to look into this.