# draw circle around mouse cursor on windows desktop

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, hook

For a presentation project, how to draw a temporary circle around mouse cursor, at the mouse click event (N.B. non only over the form, also on the Windows Desktop)

In example, like the CamStudio circle that appear at 'onMouseClick' event.
Or like the circle that appear around the mouse cursor at the click event when windows PSR.exe is running.

1. some users have recommended a transparent form to easily manage the
   onMouseClick event.

   in my opinion, this is a wrong solution for some reasons.

   The main thing is that if you create a transparent form, appear very
   hard to manage a click event, in example in the taskbar  (as pointed
   in these other discussions)

   [Form background transparency but still have click events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311592/form-background-transparency-but-still-have-click-events)

   [Keep form always on top of taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821585/keep-form-always-on-top-of-taskbar)
2. from my point of view, intuitively, the solution of the 'hooks' with
   unmanaged code, as suggested from Microsoft here
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318804/how-to-set-a-windows-hook-in-visual-c-net,
   is the best solution.

   Should be enough manage two events: the mouse click, and the event
   that enables / disable the mouseSonar.

   No transparent forms are locked as active Windows, and click on the
   taskbar, give the correct result.

   But honestly, i'm a beginner in .net, and i don't know how much it's important the unmanaged code, in the advanced programming.
3. In my opinion there would be a third solution (the one I think
   should be the best)

   If there was a class that would make the management of the
   onMouseClick event also outside the UI form bounds, the mouse click it could be
   managed with a 'safe' code.

   In example, the System.Windows.Input.MouseDevice class, and There is also a property 'OverrideCursor' that allow to set the Cursor for the entire application.

   But Microsoft Remarks: 'The MouseDevice supports the Windows
   Presentation Foundation (WPF) and is not intended to be used
   directly from your code.'

---------------------------- Update

Thanks to an user help, at this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116171/show-location-of-pointer-when-i-press-the-ctrl-key-from-code

We've found a way to set the 'Show location of pointer when I press the Ctrl key' (MOUSESONAR) by code.

Any help...

Comment: For simplicity, you may be able to have a transparent form and just draw on that (like TransparencyKey property is useful). As well as FormBorderStyle to `None`.

Comment: to add to @AlexM. comment, you also have the make it so you can click through the transparent form.

Comment: bad solution. i'd like to understand how it can be done through code.

Comment: Bad solution? You're looking at unmanaged code then. *That* is a worse solution. And you can create forms through 'code' anyway...

Comment: in example, how a program like this it's made (.net code) http://www.pointerfocus-for-presenters.com/how-to-highlight-mouse-pointer.html

Comment: @sLowDowN `TransparencyKey` makes any colour of your choice click through and transparent.

Comment: so if you want to develope a presentation program like CamStudio, what you advice? to build a transparent form? Don't know why you insist, it's a bad solution make a transparent form, a good advice could be try to understand how to do it with code

Comment: making a transparent form is a bad trick
It has nothing to do with good programming
And it is not absolutely unmanaged code, It is recommended by microsoft here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318804/how-to-set-a-windows-hook-in-visual-c-net

Comment: It has no sense what you told. as i wrote in the beginning it's for presentation: when in example you click on a folder, if you have the transparent form as active windows, you can't click and open a folder on the desktop!!

Comment: @Marcello maybe you need to start reading the comments first before saying something that I already told you

Comment: @sLowDowN, thanks, I did not know you could click through a transparent form,

Comment: i think the @er4zox solution could be more correct solution, what do you think?

Comment: Using the approach with a transparent window seems a good solution. This article goes on in depth how to do that: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12597/OSD-window-with-animation-effect-in-C

Comment: @NineBerry Thank you very much, can i ask you why you like much more this solution than the 'hook' solution as described here? https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/74411/Getting-window-handle-from-mouse-click-anywhere-on

Comment: How would a message hook draw a circle on the desktop?

Comment: on the OnMouseClick event (even if it raised outside the form bounds), i'll just enable the mousesonar, SendKeys.Send("^"), and disable the mousesonar, as you described, in this mode no windows hidden form is the active windows. i have doubt about a transparent form locked as active windows,...if you record the desktop, it could depend the behaviour of the program 'under' your transparent active windows form, if those programs behave in a different way if are not active windows...

Comment: @Johnny Prescott, thank you, i will listen your advice

Comment: There are really two different issues that you should deal with in two separate questions. The first is to know WHEN and WHERE to draw the circle (i.e. to find out that the mouse button was pressed and where the mouse cursor is currently located). For this, you can use a Low Level Mouse Event Hook. The second question is then HOW to draw the circle animation over all other windows. For that (The HOW to draw the circle), it is best to use a transparent form. The transparent form would only be visible while the circle animation is visible. You do not use it to detect a mouse click event.

Comment: @NineBerry, Thank you very much NineBerry, sorry i've work all day and i've add an answer before read your post: i think i've found a solution based on your first advice. Thanks again, you show me the way, about your notes, seems that the 'globalmousekeyhook' i've linked in my answer, tracks keyboard, mouse, and raises common .NET events with KeyEventArgs and MouseEventArgs, so seems lots of works already made. Without code transparencies, forms, etc. and thanks to the code you provided, it's just to 'enableMouseSonar, SendKeys("^"), and DisableMouseSonar' in the GlobalHook_MouseClick event

Comment: @Johnny Prescott, Thanks, today i made a research, what do you think about my own answer to this post? Your opinion? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i started this question, the most advices i collected are to 'change to WPF'.

Seems that to manage the mouseClick event of the entire desktop (also taskbar) it's not so simple to do in a WinForm application.

In this direction i've found an help here

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/30cfa752-3bec-41dd-94a4-07fc23dda688/how-to-run-a-form-over-and-beyond-the-windows-task-bar?forum=vbgeneral

Seems to me that handle the 'Desktop Mouse click', it's not so easy to do in a WinForm app, and that the best way should be to change from WinForm to WPF...

But it's not in my plan to change.

From the other side, seems to me that some other developers (maybe skilled), approach this issue with another point of view: the 'hook' interaction between WinForm and windows API (unmanaged code).

I've found a starting page here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319524/how-to-set-a-hook-in-visual-basic-net

Found a good link here

http://joelabrahamsson.com/detecting-mouse-and-keyboard-input-with-net/

and a very good and deep explanation here:

https://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_system/keyboard/article.php/c4831/Managing-LowLevel-Keyboard-Hooks-with-the-Windows-API-for-VB-NET.htm

In particular reading this last page, let me intent that the way to learn deeply on how to build a 'well managed hook' code it's extremely hard for a person with my programming level.

So at this point, i faced two ways:

the first was to change from WinForm to WPF...

The second was to learn deeply the interaction between WinForm and Windws API (too much for me).

But i think there is another way, where i can go on developing in vb.net/c#, and i can build my app in a very brief time.

Using the already builted libraries: Googling...

http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/hook

I tested some, and then i choosed MouseKeyHook (free)

http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/MouseKeyHook

And in an handful of lines of code, i've got a solution.

I want to point out that in this mode, i don't learn the way on which the interactions between WinForm and Windows Api are made.

I learn just those few commands that let me use this library.

I think this answer could be an help to lots of different users, with different needs: as who need to swap to WPF, as who need to learn deeply, as who need a quick way.

Here the code.

```
Imports Gma.System.MouseKeyHook

Public Class Form1
    Dim m_GlobalHook As IKeyboardMouseEvents

    Private Sub Subscribe()
        m_GlobalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents()
        AddHandler m_GlobalHook.MouseClick, AddressOf m_GlobalHook_MouseClick
    End Sub

    Private Sub m_GlobalHook_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Public Sub Unsubscribe()
        RemoveHandler m_GlobalHook.MouseClick, AddressOf m_GlobalHook_MouseClick
        m_GlobalHook.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can find documentation here:

https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook

The license it's totally free (MIT license), with only a note from the author
'The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.'

The only bad thing i've found, it's that the realtime Antivirus Avira protection, Alert a false positive.
I suppose are the 'hook' routine, because i tried just to compile and execute my own coded routine 'WindowsHookEx', and Avira catch the .exe as a false positive.

Also tested on [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com) give 100% clean (0/67) also with Avira scansion.

N.B. I forgot to report the help [NineBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101087/nineberry) gave me with his [MouseSonar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx) code in another Post

```
#Region "mouseSonar"
Private Sub mouseHook_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub EnableMouseSonar()
    SetMouseSonarEnabled(True)
End Sub

Private Sub DisableMouseSonar()
    SetMouseSonarEnabled(False)
End Sub

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function SystemParametersInfo(ByVal uiAction As UInteger, ByVal uiParam As UInteger, ByVal pvParam As UInteger, ByVal fWinIni As UInteger) As Boolean
End Function

Private Sub SetMouseSonarEnabled(ByVal enable As Boolean)
    Const SPI_SETMOUSESONAR As UInteger = 4125
    Const SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE As UInteger = 1
    Const SPIF_SENDCHANGE As UInteger = 2
    If Not SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESONAR, 0, CUInt((If(enable, 1, 0))), SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE Or SPIF_SENDCHANGE) Then
        Throw New Win32Exception()
    End If
End Sub
#End Region
```

So, seems to me, it's just to call these three procedure, in the MouseClick Event, to get a circle on the mouseClick outside the WinForm, without problem to manage transparencies, forms, interaction with taskbar and coding.

```
Private Sub m_GlobalHook_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    EnableMouseSonar()
    SendKeys.Send("^")
    DisableMouseSonar()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your mouse properties and enable "Show location of pointer when I press the CTRL key".

If you press CTRL, a cirlce will appear around your mouse pointer for a short time.

[How to on Win 10](https://mcmw.abilitynet.org.uk/windows-10-finding-your-mouse-pointer/)

[How to on Win 7 + 8](https://mcmw.abilitynet.org.uk/windows-7-and-8-finding-your-mouse-pointer/)

Comment: Thank you! this is a good advice, but in .net code, do you know if there is a way to change this property through code? in the framework mouse class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.mouse(v=vs.110).aspx i don't see any properties

Answer (score 1):

I don't have anytime to search for in my older project but I did something similar in the past.

You can't use .NET to draw onscreen like you would probably want to.

What I did as a workaround was to create a transparent window that is borderless and fullscreen. You ahould be able to have it hover the taskbar without much difficulties. Then track and draw around the cursor.

I'd recommend not moving a form as I wasnt able to complety avoid the taskbar issue at the time.

Use WPF to draw as it will use hardware acceleration. winForm will not. WPF is also a lot more flexible in terms of form placement to hover the taskbar and be clickable through.

Comment: Prescot Thank you, i don't use WPF, just vb.net. you told me that in past you did something similar, but don't told me nothing about the way you use, and in particular, about the taskbar issue, how did you solve the click event? the only way come in my mind it's to usa a Windows api call like the one i wrote...

Comment: Using WPF is the whole point here. it is not the language per say but the framework with which you present your UI. winForm is the old way of doing thing back in Winfowns 95-98. WPF is way more flexible than that. You need a lot less workaround for things to work. For the taskbar, simple setting "style=none" in the XAML will render the form to always draw hover the taskbar by default. At this point, you just set it in fullscreen and you are golden. To create a WPF project, you just have to choose that when creating your project in VS. that is still done in vb.net or C#, whichever you choose.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and for your help. I will follow your advice, but not just now, because i have really no time to invest in changing the way of my programs... BTW, i think that this solution can't help me out in the main problem. Seems that even if i create a transparent form, it's really hard to 'catch' the click event by the form, as explained here in the Hans Passant reply: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311592/form-background-transparency-but-still-have-click-events but if you have a solution, i'll be very happy to change my idea!

Comment: There is no point in going further if you are already in an advanced state without WPF.  You could just catch all click since you'll will be clicking on the fullscreen form anyway. I abandonned winForm a while ago so I have no idea at this point since its so deprecated.

Comment: Thanks in next future, if i can i will swap, for now i'll try to find a good solution for anyone could be interested, for vb.net. Don't know if c# have same issue or it's managed like wpf.

Comment: No problem. However, you don't seems to get the difference. It's not about the language but the framework. C# and VB.NET will be exactly the same as they are the same language and are compile by the same backend. Search for solution on the internet that are specific to winForm, not VB. If you are using winForm, VS should give you a photoshop like interface to modify the ui while WPF (Windows presentation Foundation) will use XAML language to build the UI. Both can be done in vb, c# or F# but the calls made to the ui are different. I dont think winForm has been updated in a while now.